# Not moving on X and Y axis

Tags: stepper, creality-ender-5, creality

**TL;DR**

I moved the printer head slightly without turning off the system and now only the Z-axis stepper motors work.

---

I recently purchased an Ender 5 Plus. I managed to get three prints done and then one print went bad. The nozzle scraped against the glass plate (causing me to have to replace the nozzle). For some reason my home coordinates changed and caused the plate to eventually press all the way against the nozzle. During this my BLTouch also bent and needs to be replaced.

The big problem now is that none of the motors are working (except for the Z-axis steppers). I had an air headed moment and moved the printer head while the machine was on (but not printing). Now the BLTouch is static red and only the Z-axis motors works. I've tried every bit of advice I could find. Any chance anyone has a possible solution?

Comment: Hi. If you tried every bit of advice you could find, it would be really hard to give another better advice. Maybe if you describe what you have already tried and what you already checked? Just few sample questions: are X,Y stepper motors powered (you could hear it)? Are stepper cables ok? Disable the power, and try to connect X motor instead of Z (its slot on the mainboard) - will the X work then? How strong had the nozzle crashed into the bed, so that you "have to replace the nozzle"? I can't imagine that. This sounds like your motors had been powered so much, that they won't skip any steps?

Comment: I do not think moving the head or plate with you hands, while the system is powered will ruin anything. 

What will ruin things is if you disconnect any cables to the motors while the system is on and the stepper motor is enabled (stiff or moving). Then that stepper driver will go bad. I googled the mainboard for your printer and it look like the drivers are soldered directly on the mainboard. If any of them are bad, then I guess best thing is to replace the mainboard.